# problemas con numeros en memoria compartida linux

Tags: c, linux, manejo-de-memoria, proceso

Estoy intentando pasar números entre procesos Linux vía memoria compartida, me funciona correctamente con strings pero en cambio al pasar cualquier número via memoria compartida me sale un número distinto erróneo, por ejemplo si escribo el **0** el programa me muestra **-1678614528**.

El código es el siguiente:

step1.c:

```
key_t key = ftok("shmfile",65); 
int shmid = shmget(key,1024,0666|IPC_CREAT); 
int *num = shmat(shmid,(void*)0,0); 
char *str = (char*) shmat(shmid,(void*)0,0);
 while(num!=0){
    printf("write num\n");
    scanf("%d",num); 
    printf("write data\n");
    scanf("%s",str); 
    printf("num written in memory: %d\n",num); 
    printf("str written in memory: %s\n",str); 
    shmdt(num); 
    shmdt(str); 
    num =  shmat(shmid,(void*)0,0); 
    str = (char*) shmat(shmid,(void*)0,0); 
 }
```

step2.c:

```
key_t key = ftok("shmfile",65); 
int *num = shmat(shmid,(void*)0,0);
char *str = (char*) shmat(shmid,(void*)0,0); 
while(num!=0){
    printf("num read from memory: %d\n",num);
    printf("str read from memory: %s\n",str); 
    shmdt(str); 
    str = (char*) shmat(shmid,(void*)0,0); 
            shmdt(num); 
    num = shmat(shmid,(void*)0,0); 
}

shmctl(shmid,IPC_RMID,NULL);
```

Comment: si no tienes problemas con cadenas pon un prefijo por ejemplo "n" a los números y al recuperarlos lo quitas. Dos pasos extra y mucho ahorro de tiempo buscando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te estás equivocando sobre como funcionan los segmentos de memoria compartida.

> #### void *shmat( int shmid, const void *shmaddr, int shmflg );
>
> La  función  `shmat( )`  pega el segmento de memoria compartida identificada por `shmid` al espacio de direcciones del proceso que llama a la función.

La función trabaja **por bloques de memoria**, no por variables. El bloque de memoria completo es *compartido* entre procesos. Una vez hecho eso, lo único que se necesita es ponernos de acuerdo en que direcciones relativas (dentro del bloque) va a ocupar cada variable.

Un bloque en memoria sería tal que así:

> [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
>    0                                                        ...                                               X

En donde cada *cuadro* (`[ ]`) representa un *byte*.

En tu caso, solo se quieren compartir un entero y una cadena. Dejaremos que el entero ocupe la posición relativa `0`, y la cadena ocupará la posición relativa `sizeof( int )`. Así tenemos casi todo el espacio disponible para la cadena, mientras que el `int` ocupará solo el tamaño necesario:

> [num][num][num][num][str][str][str][str][str][str][str][str]    ...    [str]

Con lo que, si hacemos

```
char *ptr = shmat( ... );
```

`(int *)ptr` contendría la variable `num` (desplazamiento `0`), y `ptr + sizeof( int )` contendrá el punto de inicio de la variable `str`.

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta es que **el orden** de las operaciones es importante. Tenemos que asegurarnos, antes de leer, que los datos han sido escritos. En este ejemplo, después de duplicar el proceso con `fork( )`, esperamos hasta que el hijo muera. Así estamos seguros de que las escrituras ya se han realizado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

static const char *SHMPATH = "/tmp/shmfile";
static int SHMPROJ = 65;

static void writer( ) {
  key_t key = ftok( SHMPATH, SHMPROJ );
  int shmid = shmget( key, 1024, 0666 | IPC_CREAT );

  int *num = (int *)shmat( shmid, NULL, 0 );
  char *str = (char *)( num + 1 );

  printf( "write num: " );
  scanf( "%d", num );
  printf( "write data: " );
  scanf( "%s", str );
  printf( "num written in memory: %d\n", *num );
  printf( "data written in memory: %s\n", str );
}

static void reader( ) {
  key_t key = ftok( SHMPATH, SHMPROJ );
  int shmid = shmget( key, 1024, 0666 | IPC_CREAT );

  int *num = (int *)shmat( shmid, NULL, 0 );
  char *str = (char *)( num + 1 );

  printf( "\nREADED\n\nnum: %d\ndata %s\n", *num, str );
}

int main( void ) {    
  if( !fork( ) ) {
    // Proceso writer.
    writer( );
  } else {
    // Proceso reader.
    // Esperamos hasta que el hijo muera.
    wait( NULL );

    reader( );    
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Fíjate que **solo llamamos 1 vez por proceso** a las funciones de memoria compartida.